# Matching variables in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a requirement in my project that I create a predicate named is_category(C), which checks if this C exists in my database or not here is an example to clarify:

```
is_category(animals):-
true.
```

Another one:

```
is_category(C):-
C= animals;
C= animals;
C= greetings;
C= fruits;
C= animals;
C= collections.
```

And my facts are:

```
word(horse,animals).
word(panda,animals).
word(hello,greetings).
word(banana,fruits).
word(bison,animals).
word(hoard,collections).
```

Now my question is how to do this requirement as my only solution I thought about was to just ask if there were any category named animals and use the key cut, it shows one true but it only shows the word animals and stop so please assist me if you can.

Here is my thought:

```
is_category(C):-
word(_,C),!.
```

Comment: It seems to me that `is_category(C):- word(_,C).` (without the cut) is all you need. What is the problem with that?

Comment: The answer will be
    is_category(animals):-
    True;
    True;
    True;
    True.
And it wants only to output one true

Comment: Can you clarify if you can?

Comment: Clarify what? In the comments for the deleted answer, you said, "But the requirement was to output all the categories available like I showed". You haven't showed that. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score -1):

You can use predicate like this:

```
is_category(Category) :-
  setof(Category, Word^word(Word, Category), Categories),
  member(Category, Categories).
```

So for this knowledge base:

```
word(horse,animals).
word(panda,animals).
word(hello,greetings).
word(banana,fruits).
word(bison,animals).
word(hoard,collections).
```

You can ask "Is there a word with category animal?"

```
?- is_category(animals).
true
```

And on backtracking generate all possible distinct (and sorted) categories:

```
?- is_category(Category).
Category = animals ;
Category = collections ;
Category = fruits ;
Category = greetings ;
false.
```

Comment: It would be great if you showed the facts and the results of querying using this predicate.